# Problem in BLE connection with start_notify and write_gatt_char Bleak, python on windows

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm not able to receive response from my device via BLE communication. The device has an characteristic UUID in write and notify. I work on a windows system with python. I use Bleak library. The following one is my code:

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient

WRITE_NOTIFY_ID = "00001111-2222-aaaa-3333-444geabcd123" #this UUID is fake to privacy
address_T = "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF" #this address is fake to privacy


def notification_handler(sender: WRITE_NOTIFY_ID, data: bytearray):
        print(f"{sender}: {data}")

async def main(address):
    async with BleakClient(address) as client:

        if (not client.is_connected):
            raise "client not connected"

        await client.start_notify(WRITE_NOTIFY_ID, notification_handler)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        answer= await client.write_gatt_char(WRITE_NOTIFY_ID, b'\x24', response=True)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print(answer)
        await client.stop_notify(WRITE_NOTIFY_ID)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  asyncio.run(main(address_T))
```

I try many options. I expect to receive something to print.

Comment: I am not familiar with the library you use but I guess you did not write Client Configuration Descriptor that is required step.

Comment: I'm not familiar too with this library, but also with bluetooth communication in general.  What is this Client configuration Descriptor? the address is right and also I used other code to obtain services and characteristic and it goes properly. I have problem only with this functions

Comment: https://www.btframework.com/gatt.htm#CharacteristicValueChangeNotifications

Comment: Also the lib is compitible with Python on Windows platforms (https://github.com/btframework/WCL-Python-Demos)

Comment: Thank you all for your support!